# Python keep printing if one of the values is empty. csv dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, try-catch

Some of the `desc` items might be empty. Is that why the csv is blank? How can I make it ignore and keep printing?

```
        try:
            name = div.find_element_by_class_name('styles_itemNameText__3bcKX')
            price = div.find_element_by_class_name('rupee')
            desc = div.find_element_by_class_name('styles_itemDesc__MTsVd')
            dict1 = {'Item Name': name.text, "Price": price.text, "Description": desc.text}
            with open(f'{search_city}_{res_n}.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict1.keys())
                if not header_added:
                    w.writeheader()
                    header_added = True
                w.writerow(dict1)
        except:
```

Comment: Can you try to add this line to above dict1: `description = desc.text if desc else ""`. after that change dict1's "Description" with `description` variable.

Comment: It skips the elements with no description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try:
    name = div.find_element_by_class_name('styles_itemNameText__3bcKX')
    price = div.find_element_by_class_name('rupee')
    
    # What i added
    if div.find_elements_by_class_name('styles_itemDesc__MTsVd'):
        desc = div.find_element_by_class_name('styles_itemDesc__MTsVd').text
    else:
        desc = None

    dict1 = {'Item Name': name.text, "Price": price.text, "Description": desc}
    with open(f'{search_city}_{res_n}.csv', 'a+', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, dict1.keys())
        if not header_added:
            w.writeheader()
            header_added = True
        w.writerow(dict1)
except:
```

Use an if statement to set the value of `desc` depending on the condition.